# Is multi-processing, compared with multi-threading, just a way to gain more cpu resources?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

Multi-processing utilizes multi-core CPU by distributing tasks to many processes. This makes CPU handle "this program's tasks" more frequently, since different core can load different process and executes at the same time. On the other hand, my understanding of multi-threading is that different threads from the same process can also be loaded to different CPU cores to run concurrently. So if we put inter-process/inter-thread communication aside, is multi-processing just a way to gain more cpu resources? I use both techniques without fully understanding what happens at firmware/hardware level...

Let's say, I have a program handling a bunch of totally CPU-bound tasks with same body and different parameters. These tasks can be fully parallelly processed. What would be different if I use multi-processing (N processes) vs multi-threading (N threads)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to pure computational power in average computers, there is usually no difference in performance, they are both ways to utilize multiple cores. (IPC and startup overhead aside)

When it comes to HPC (high performance computing), multiple processes can have different resources allocated to each process, (each NUMA node in a NUMA cluster has its own private memory), which achieves higher throughput by less resources contention (including cores contention), NUMA nodes aside, you can also pin each process to certain cores, for time-critical applications where you cannot rely on the OS scheduler to prioritize your process, and manage the priority of each process manually.

similar functionality can be done on threads in some systems, but it requires major code modifications, while the process-based approach is simpler and more portable.

Having multiple processes allows scalability and isolation

1. later on you can have each process working on a different computer, which is connected over the network (cluster computing)
2. you have better error handling in case one worker fails or crashes (kubernetes)
3. you can have each team working on a different "process" in your application.

In short, threads are useful if you are doing a small computation concurrently or need the shared address space for low latency, but if you are doing an application-scale computation, then it's best to isolate it in its own Process/Application, this is how most simulators work, in such applications both multiprocessing and multithreading go hand-in-hand, so you have multiple processes each with its own multiple threads.

Comment: The part about NUMA/HPC does not seems relevant to me: this behaviour is not really different between multithreading and multiprocessing. In both cases, the allocated memory can be spread between multiple NUMA nodes. Threads like processes can also be pinned to cores. Besides, processes tends to consume more memory since it is not shared by default (though the OS generally performs a COW optimization) an people tends to rarely use it manually.

Comment: Thank you for the answer with solid explanation!

@JérômeRichard I guess inter-thread communication in NUMA costs much more than in average computer, right? I understand that, in average computer, inter-thread communication is easier than inter-process ones because process has isolated memory area.  So I guess thread to another thread in different NUMA node is somehow like inter-process things since they are in different memory?

Comment: @unsatisfiablespirit Modern machines are nearly always NUMA one from the hardware point-of-view. PC can be abstracted as UMA machines from a high-level point-of-view (mainly because most processors are either able to hide NUMA effects or just have one memory controller) though they are actually NUMA. This abstraction is often fine since the NUMA effect on PC are generally negligible. This is generally not the case on computing servers. This is a complex topic (more than it seems). For more information, please read [this](https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf).

Comment: @unsatisfiablespirit Regarding the simplicity, it is hard to say. Multithreading and multiprocessing are not very different in practice (especially when they are abstracted using a high-level library). They should not be confused with the communication model: shared-memory and message-passing. Multithreading is generally related to shared-memory and multiprocessing related to message-passing, but this is not mandatory. Shared memory is generally considered simpler (though not every one agree on this). For more details, books are probably a good start.

Comment: @JérômeRichard "In both cases, the allocated memory can be spread between multiple NUMA nodes." you can restrict the node(s) which a process' memory is mapped to and make the system schedule the process' tasks only on the nodes' cpus. this is the way to guarantee the process' threads won't access memory from the other nodes.